# Is there an easier method to find filename when downloading file with curl

Tags: c++, libcurl

I need to implement the following strategy for naming a file that I want to download by HTTP using some URL:

1. If a response has a `filename=` field - use it. This field, for example, may be inside the `Content-Disposition` header;
2. If previous point doesn't work, try to get filename from URL;
3. If previous point doesn't work, use some arbitrary name, e.g. using `CoCreateGuid` WinAPI function.

Now I have an `CurlBuffer`-object of custom class, a callback to writing data from curl and a callback for writing headers:

```
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &currentBuffer); //  currentBuffer is CurlBuffer-object
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, &currentBuffer);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, ResponseHeaderWriter);
```

So now in the `ResponseHeaderWriteCallback` I'm checking the headers for `filename=` field, if it exists and valid I mark it in the `currentBuffer`. Because the `WriteCallback` called immediately after all headers been read, I cann't execute any code to hold a situation when there is no `filename=` field in the headers. So in `WriteCallback` I should check weather filename was found and if it's not, I should call some other functions to get the filename.
It looks something like that:

```
size_t WriteCallback(void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp)
{
    auto* curlBuffer = static_cast<CurlBuffer*>(userp);
    // some other code
    // Find a new filename if it's a first call to WriteCallback and the filename wasn't found
    if (!curlBuffer->HasFinalFilePath() && curlBuffer->Size() == 0) {
        static const std::string dummy;
        // gotFileNameFromHeader is a callback to assign the name to file. This callback is bad itself and has a bad name right now.
        curlBuffer->gotFileNameFromHeader(curlBuffer, dummy, *curlBuffer->url);
    }
    // some other code
    return actualSize;
}

size_t ResponseHeaderWriter(void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp)
{
    auto* writeBuffer = static_cast<CurlBuffer*>(userp);
    if (writeBuffer) {
        writeBuffer->headers.push_back(std::string((char*)contents, size * nmemb));
        const auto& fileName = GetFileNameFromHeader(writeBuffer ->headers.back());
        if (!fileName.empty() && writeBuffer ->gotFileNameFromHeader) {
            writeBuffer ->gotFileNameFromHeader(writeBuffer, fileName, *writeBuffer->url);
        }
    }

    return size * nmemb;
}
```

The actual code is much longer and has two levels of callbacks, I mean that a function calls callback which calls another callback. The code is already quite difficult and ugly. I also want to add ability to finish incomplete downloading - and it will clutter the code even more. So, may be I'm doing something wrong? If I understand it correctly, it is possible to send HEAD-request firstly, but I had read somewhere that server may not handle this type of requests, so I still need all that code, am I?

Comment: You could finish it so that it works, clutter and all, and then post it on Code Review for suggestions on how to make it cleaner.

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Comment: My immediate reaction would be to start by always generating a GUID, and using that as the initial file name. Then after you're finished downloading, check whether you've received information to give a better filename, and if so, rename the file to that name.

Comment: *Because the WriteCallback called immediately after all headers been read* This is false. A header callback raises "\r\n" before WriteCallback.